# Export transactions require name and address of the customer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am using nodeJS to integrate stripe

```
app.post('/api/stripe', async (req, res) => {
    const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
        amount: 500,
        currency: 'usd',
        source: req.body.id,
        description: '$5 for 5 creidts',
    });
    console.log(charge)
})

export default billingRoutes
```

All these are in test environment and when I run this, I get the following error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: As per Indian regulations, export transactions require a customer name and address. More info here: https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports
> [0]     at Function.generate (/home/vaibhav/Documents/email-app/email-server/node_modules/stripe/lib/Error.js:40:16)
> [0]     at IncomingMessage. (/home/vaibhav/Documents/email-app/email-server/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:180:33)
> [0]     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
> [0]     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
> [0]     at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
> [0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)

According to doc https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports I had to replace the above code with

```
const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
            name: 'Vaibhav',
            address: {                
                line1: 'line1 addres',
                postal_code: '500001',
                city: 'Hyderabad',
                state: 'Telangana',
                country: 'India',
            },            
            amount: 500,
            currency: 'usd',
            source: req.body.id,
            description: '$5 for 5 creidts',
        });
```

now when I give this I am getting the following error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Received unknown parameters: name, address
[0]     at Function.generate (/home/vaibhav/Documents/email-app/email-server/node_modules/stripe/lib/Error.js:40:16)
[0]     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/vaibhav/Documents/email-app/email-server/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:180:33)
[0]     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
[0]     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
[0]     at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

This self contradictory isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

`name` & `address` are not valid parameters when [creating a Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create).

As per the doc, you should instead [create a new Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create) object, passing the `name` & `address` parameters as required. Then pass the newly created Customer object ID (`cus_xxx`) as a [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create#create_charge-customer) for the API call that creates the Charge.

```js
const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
  name: 'Vaibhav',
  address: {                
    line1: 'line1 addres',
    postal_code: '500001',
    city: 'Hyderabad',
    state: 'Telangana',
    country: 'IN',
  }
});

const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 500,
  customer: customer.id,
  currency: 'usd',
  source: req.body.id,
  description: '$5 for 5 creidts',
});
```

Comment: I have read that just now and made the changes you suggested.
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Customer cus_JejRqiofeWuw1k does not have a linked source with ID tok_1J1PynSCMGuUTRUtpckl9wqW.`
this is the error that I have received. I am trying to figure out how the customer ID and token( which is generated in the front end ) can be linked together.

Comment: That's right, a token cannot be associated with a Customer object. Generally we recommend working with [PaymentIntents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents) now as opposed to Charges, which is highlighted in that doc you share in your original question. They're the newer API for handling all payment scenarios with Stripe.